# Android get value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, shared

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store the choice between `2 checkboxes`. 
It works but now I want that if the value is = 0 must be started my method, if it is equal to 1 is to be launched another method. I created a simple "if" but the method is not launched. Do you have any idea how to do?

```
sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    Integer value = sharedPreference.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, -1);
             Log.d("va", "value: "+value);
             if (value.equals(0)){


             }else{

             }
```

Comment: Can you verify the value is what you expected? ie. Are you always getting 0? or -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int value = sharedPreference.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, -1);
         Log.d("va", "value: "+value);
         if (value == 0){


         }else{

         }
```

A cleaner example

```
int value = sharedPreference.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, -1);
    switch(value){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
    }
```